# How can I create a Directional(Angled) Marker in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have the angle of the marker, I just want that the marker gets rotated to that angles.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                location: LocInfo,
                map: map,
                title: titleInfo,
                icon: image,
                html: text,
                angle: 150 // i want to do something like this
            });
```

Is there any property like angle property that I can use like in above example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few search I have found the answer and it works.

```
var angleDegrees = 150;
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: a,
        map: map,
        icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
            scale: 6,
            fillColor: "red",
            fillOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            rotation: angleDegrees //this is how to rotate the pointer
        }  
    });
```